# Como aplicar efeito hover (JQuery) a um grupo específico de classes?

Tags: jquery, html, css-hover

Eu estou criando uma página web que seria algo como uma loja. A ideia desse código é que, ao dar hover na div .lojaprodutos, apareçam duas outras divs (uma à direita e outra embaixo), e esse efeito precisa ser feito em JQuery/Javascript. O problema é que, como a página vai comportar vários produtos, será necessário vários dessas divs (motivo pelo qual essas divs recebem classes, e não IDs). O problema é que, apesar de eu ter alcançado o efeito com JQuery/Javascript, ao dar hover na classe, todas as divs sofrem o efeito.

A minha dúvida é: como aplicar esse efeito a apenas a um grupo dessas três divs? Para não haver confusão, como aplicar esse efeito apenas nas divs dentro da div #divisao1, #divisao2, etc.?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxHeight = $(".box").height();
  $(".lojaprodutos,.lojaavaliacao,.lojaespecificacao").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".lojaavaliacao").css({
      'width': '15vw'
    });
    $(".lojaespecificacao").css({
      'height': '15vw'
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".lojaavaliacao").css({
      'width': '0'
    });
    $(".lojaespecificacao").css({
      'height': '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#divisao1 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 35vw;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#divisao2 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 35vw;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaprodutos {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin-left: 7.5vw;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: pink;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaavaliacao {
  width: 0;
  height: 16vw;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 27.5vw;
  margin-top: -18vw;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaespecificacao {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 7.5vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  background: orange;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efeito hover</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divisao1">
    <div class="lojaprodutos">Como ativar o efeito só aqui?</div>
    <div class="lojaavaliacao"></div>
    <div class="lojaespecificacao"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="divisao2">
    <div class="lojaprodutos">Ou só aqui?</div>
    <div class="lojaavaliacao"></div>
    <div class="lojaespecificacao"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O efeito é suposto afetar todos ou só aquele em que se fez *hover* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o seletor `this` para alcançar somente o elemento que sofre o evento, e atribuindo os eventos ao elemento *div* pai fica mais fácil de acessar os filhos através da função `find`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxHeight = $(".box").height();
  $("div.loja").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".lojaavaliacao").css({
      'width': '15vw'
    });
    $(this).find(".lojaespecificacao").css({
      'height': '15vw'
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".lojaavaliacao").css({
      'width': '0'
    });
    $(this).find(".lojaespecificacao").css({
      'height': '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#divisao1 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 35vw;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#divisao2 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 35vw;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaprodutos {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  margin-left: 7.5vw;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: pink;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaavaliacao {
  width: 0;
  height: 16vw;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 27.5vw;
  margin-top: -18vw;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.lojaespecificacao {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 7.5vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  background: orange;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efeito hover</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divisao1" class="loja">
    <div class="lojaprodutos">Como ativar o efeito só aqui?</div>
    <div class="lojaavaliacao"></div>
    <div class="lojaespecificacao"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="divisao2" class="loja">
    <div class="lojaprodutos">Ou só aqui?</div>
    <div class="lojaavaliacao"></div>
    <div class="lojaespecificacao"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Uma breve explicação das mudanças seria interessante para a comunidade!

Comment: Adicionei a explicação

Comment: agora sim, beleza +1